# get string value from textfield in nstableview

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

i have a nstableview with a custom cell.
(4 rows, one textfield per row)

i have a nstableview controller and a custom cell class
into the nstableview class i putted this delegate methode:

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {

   print("Edit") 
   return true
}
```

when i change a nstextfield value in my nstableview i get an "Edit" print. but now i have to know, what is the new value of edited textfield.

how can i get this?

swift 3, osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    print("new text is \(fieldEditor.string!)
    return true
}
```

You'll find the new text in the `fieldEditor` parameter of that delegate method.

Right now you have this delegate method in your NSTableView class.  I suggest moving it to your custom cell class and reset your delegate to point to the custom cell.

Then, if you assign each of the four textfields to `@IBOutlet` properties, you can easily see which field this belongs to.  That is:

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell : NSTableViewCell, NSControlTextEditingDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField : NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryField : NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var anotherTextField : NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var andYetAnotherTextField : NSTextField!

    func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {

         if control == self.nameField {
              print("new nameField text is is \(fieldEditor.string!)
         }
         if control == self.categoryField {
              print("new categoryField text is is \(fieldEditor.string!)
         }
         if control == self.anotherTextField {
              print("new anotherTextField text is is \(fieldEditor.string!)
         }
         if control == self.andYetAnotherTextField {
              print("new andYetAnotherTextField text is is \(fieldEditor.string!)
         }
    return true
}
```

I *think* this will also work with a `switch` statement (e.g. `switch(control)` and `case self.nameField`).

Comment: thanks for this good solution :) but how i know from which textfield this value is?

Comment: I edited to show how you can use the delegate method's `control` parameter.